# Cannot click on google's new reCaptcha tick box using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to download all the images of recaptcha but somehow I am not able to click on the reCaptcha iframe's checkbox.
When clicking on it the HtmlUnit throws the WrappedException. I am not sure why this is happening and 
How am I suppose to click on the link and download the images? My guess is this is the problem with the GWT. I can click any other normal button.

Any help will be highly appreciated

The main site is: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

Here I have done so far.

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38)) {
            webClient.getCache().clear();
            final WebClientOptions webClientOptions = webClient.getOptions();
            webClientOptions.setTimeout(40000);
            webClientOptions.setRedirectEnabled(false);
            // webClientOptions.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
            webClient.setAlertHandler(new AlertHandler() {
                public void handleAlert(Page page, String string) {
                    System.out.printf("alert: %s%n", string);
                    LOG.info("javascript alert: {}", string);
                }
            });
            webClientOptions.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
          //  webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
            webClientOptions.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClientOptions.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);


            HtmlPage reCaptchaFrame;

            final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo");
            webClient.getJavaScriptEngine().pumpEventLoop(1000);
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(200);

            int waitForBackgroundJavaScript = webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(200);
            int loopCount = 0;
            while (waitForBackgroundJavaScript > 0 && loopCount < 2) {
                ++loopCount;
                waitForBackgroundJavaScript = webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(200);
                if (waitForBackgroundJavaScript == 0) {
                    if (LOG.isTraceEnabled())
                        LOG.trace("HtmlUnit exits background javascript at loop counter " + loopCount);
                    break;
                 }
            }

            JavaScriptEngine engine = webClient.getJavaScriptEngine();
            engine.holdPosponedActions();
            final List<FrameWindow> frames = page.getFrames();

            reCaptchaFrame = (HtmlPage) frames.get(0).getEnclosedPage();
            // initiating to enter the reCaptcha

            final HtmlSpan reCaptchaAnchor =  reCaptchaFrame.getFirstByXPath(".//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']");

            if (reCaptchaAnchor == null) {
                 throw new NullPointerException("Captcha not found");
            }

            try {
                 HtmlPage page1 = reCaptchaAnchor.click(); // here I get the exception

            } catch (WrappedException e) {
                 LOG.info("Found some stupid exception {}", e.details());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("Found exception {}", e.getMessage());
        } 
     }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException
at     net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Con text.java:2053)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:1007)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.processPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:1072)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:789)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:732)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:679)
at recaptchatest.Main.main(Main.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.hasTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3263)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:102)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Promise$1.execute(Promise.java:136)
at      com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:1002)
... 10 more
```

Comment: is this still working for you with 2.22 ? I get the message *Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again.*

Comment: @MajidLaissi Did you get a solution?

Comment: click on  HtmlPage page1 = reCaptchaAnchor.click(); doesnt work..  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading HTMLUnit to 2.22 and htmlunit-core-js library to 2.22 everything working as expected.

Comment: Any updates on this ? 
am trying this code and it's failing ! with version 2.22 ... I am getting null: here

final HtmlSpan reCaptchaAnchor =  reCaptchaFrame.getFirstByXPath(".//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']");
I tried also version 2.33 ... and I am getting 0 Frames

Can someone post working version ?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to check what is the actual XPATH of the element.

The box has a  with class='recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark'

You may use XPath with:

```
 reCaptchaFrame.getFirstByXPath("//div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark']");
```

If it fails, try to use another selection methods other than XPATH, probably the CSS one, which is queryselector method.

Which is:

```
reCaptchaFrame.querySelector("recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark");
```

To assign without casting errors occur, please use HtmlElement to cast all of the element on the web.

```
HtmlElement a = reCaptchaFrame.querySelector("recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark");
a.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my case upgrading core JS library solve the issue.